# Plug-in estimator $1/\lambda$ and standard error

Tags: mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution, standard-error

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n ∼ \mathsf{Pois}(λ).$ Find the plug-in estimator $\hat \tau$ for $\tau = 1/λ$ and calculate the standard error.

I thought:

$\hat\lambda =\bar X $ (sample mean) so $\hat\tau = 1/\hat λ = {\bar X}^{-1}.$

$V[\hat\tau] = V[{\bar X}^{-1}],$ but then
can I conclude, since $V[\bar X] = \sigma^2/n,$ that $V[{\bar X}^{-1}]=n/\sigma^2?$

Comment: Started to edit your Question for readability, but someone else was editing simultaneously. Please check that the result did not change your meaning. // In your last sentence, it is not necessarily true that $E(1/X) = 1/E(X),$ so you need to think about that part.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: Also, do you want the actual standard error of $\hat\tau$ or the standard error of the asymptotic distribution as $n\to\infty$, via something like the delta method? The actual variance (and thus standard deviation) of $\hat\tau$ is infinite, because $\bar X$ is sometimes zero.